# Split list based on when a pattern of consecutive numbering stops

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have an existing list. I want to break it up into separate lists whenever the following number is not equal to its preceding value.

```
x = [1,4,4,5,5,8,8,10,10,25,25,70,70,90,90,100,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,8,8,9,20,21,21,22,23)
```

The desired output should look like this:

```
 a = [1,4,4,5,5,8,8,10,10,25,25,70,70,90,90,100)

 b = [2,3,3,4,4,5,5,8,8,9)

 c = [20,21,21,22]

 d = [23]
```

Comment: So `[1,1,3,3,2,5]` will become `[[1,1],[3,3],[2],[5]]`?

Comment: @HennyH output separate lists so a list [1,1,3,3] and a list [2,5]..

Comment: I don't get it. Why doesn't the first split occur at 13?

Comment: apologies @stranac it should, will edit post now

Comment: What's the expected output for `x = [1,4,4,5,5,5,8,8,10,11,11,12]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numpy version:

```
>>> inds = np.where(np.diff(x))[0]
>>> out = np.split(x,inds[np.diff(inds)==1][0::2]+2)
>>> for n in out:
...     print n

[  38 1200 1200  306  306  391  391   82   82   35   35  902  902  955  955
   13]
[955 847 847 835 835 698 698 777 777 896 896 923 923 940 940 569 569  53
  53 411]
[  53 1009 1009 1884]
[1009  878]
[ 923  886  886  511  511  942  942 1067 1067 1888 1888  243  243 1556]
```

Your new case is the same:

```
>>> inds = np.where(np.diff(x))[0]
>>> out = np.split(x,inds[np.diff(inds)==1][0::2]+2)
>>> for n in out:
...     print n
...
[  1   4   4   5   5   8   8  10  10  25  25  70  70  90  90 100]
[2 3 3 4 4 5 5 8 8 9]
[20 21 21 22]
[23]
```

Starting with `x` as list:

```
%timeit inds = np.where(np.diff(x))[0];out = np.split(x,inds[np.diff(inds)==1][0::2]+2)
10000 loops, best of 3: 169 µs per loop
```

If `x` is a numpy array:

```
%timeit inds = np.where(np.diff(arr_x))[0];out = np.split(arr_x,inds[np.diff(inds)==1][0::2]+2)
10000 loops, best of 3: 135 µs per loop
```

For larger systems you can likely expect numpy to have better performance vs pure python.

Answer (score 4):

In order to answer your question:

> I have [...] a list. I want to break it up into separate lists whenever the following number is not equal to its preceding value.

Have a look at [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

Example:

```
import itertools
l = [38, 1200, 1200, 306, 306, 391, 391, 82, 82, 35, 35, 902, 902, 955, 955, 13]
for x, v in itertools.groupby(l):
    # `v` is an iterator that yields all subsequent elements
    # that have the same value
    # `x` is that value
    print list(v)
```

The output is:

```
$ python test.py
[38]
[1200, 1200]
[306, 306]
[391, 391]
[82, 82]
[35, 35]
[902, 902]
[955, 955]
[13]
```

Which is apparently what you are asking for?

---

As for your pattern thing, here's some generator function that, at the very least, produces the output you expect for the given input:

```
import itertools

def split_sublists(input_list):
    sublist = []
    for val, l in itertools.groupby(input_list):
        l = list(l)
        if not sublist or len(l) == 2:
            sublist += l
        else:
            sublist += l
            yield sublist
            sublist = []
    yield sublist

input_list = [1,4,4,5,5,8,8,10,10,25,25,70,70,90,90,100,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,8,8,9,20,21,21,22,23]
for sublist in split_sublists(input_list):
    print sublist
```

The output:

```
$ python test.py
[1, 4, 4, 5, 5, 8, 8, 10, 10, 25, 25, 70, 70, 90, 90, 100]
[2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 8, 8, 9]
[20, 21, 21, 22]
[23]
```

Comment: Why not put `sublist += l` out of the `if/else` and get rid of the `else` entirely?

Comment: @stranac You'd still need a check whether or not you've just inserted the first element to the sublist or not. Plus, the first rule of optimization: Don't do it.

Comment: It's not about optimization, it's about writing better code, and not repeating yourself needlessly. You would still use `if sublist and len(l) != 2:` to do the necessary checking, and put all the two lines there. The else block would then not be needed.

Comment: Actually, sorry, I wasn't paying enough attention

Answer (score 1):

```
def group(l,skip=0):
    prevind = 0
    currind = skip+1
    for val in l[currind::2]:
        if val != l[currind-1]:
            if currind-prevind-1 > 1: yield l[prevind:currind-1]
            prevind = currind-1
        currind += 2
    if prevind != currind:
        yield l[prevind:currind]
```

Which for the list you defined, returns when called with `skip=1`

```
[38, 1200, 1200, 306, 306, 391, 391, 82, 82, 35, 35, 902, 902, 955, 955]
[13, 955, 847, 847, 835, 835, 698, 698, 777, 777, 896, 896, 923, 923, 940, 940, 569, 569, 53, 53]
[411, 53, 1009, 1009]
[1884, 1009]
[878, 923, 886, 886, 511, 511, 942, 942, 1067, 1067, 1888, 1888, 243, 243, 1556]
```

And a simpler example list `[1,1,3,3,2,5]`:

```
for g in group(l2):
    print g

[1, 1, 3, 3]
[2, 5]
```

The reason `skip` is an optional parameter to the function is that in your example *38* was included despite it not being equal to *1200*. If this was an error, then simply remove skip and set `currind` to equal `1` initially.

---

**Explanation:**

In a list `[a,b,c,d,e,...]`. We want to compare two elements with each other in succession i.e `a == b`, `c == d`, and then when a comparison doesn't return `True`, capture all previous elements (excluding those already captured). To do this we need to keep track of where the last capture took place, which initially is `0` (i.e no captures). We then go over each of the pairs, by going over ever *2nd* element in the list starting at `currind` which by default (when not skipping an element) is one. And then compare the value we get from `l[currind::2]` to the value before it `l[currind-1]`. `currind` is the index of each *2nd* element from `currind`'s inital value (`1` by default). If the values *don't* match then we need to perform a capture but only if the resulting capture would contain a term! Hence `currind-prevind-1` > 1 (because the list slice will be that length -1, so it needs to be 2 or more to extract at least 1 element). `l[prevind:currind-1]` does this capture, going from the index of the last comparison which didn't match (or `0` the default) up till the element ***before*** first value in each comparison pair `a,b` or `c,d` etc.. Then `prevind` is set to `currind-1` i.e the index of the last element captured. We then increment `currind` by 2 to go to the index of the next `val`. Then finally, if there was a pair left over we extract it.

So for `[1,1,3,3,2,5]`:

```
val is 1, at index 1. comparing to value at 0 i.e 1
make currind the index of last element of the next pair
val is 3, at index 3. comparing to value at 2 i.e 3
make currind the index of last element of the next pair
val is 5, at index 5. comparing to value at 4 i.e 2
not equal so get slice between 0,4
[1, 1, 3, 3]
make currind the index of last element of the next pair  #happens after the for loop
[2, 5]
```

Comment: This doesn't give the same output as asked for.

Comment: @Veedrac his output is 'wrong'. It isn't consistent with itself.

Comment: @HennyH I get your output for the l2 you defined but not for x = [38, 1200, 1200, 306, 306, 391, 391, 82, 82, 35, 35, 902, 902, 955, 955, 13, 955, 847, 847, 835, 83, 5698, 698, 777, 777, 896, 896, 923, 923, 940, 940, 569, 569, 53, 53, 411]. I get [38, 1200]
[1200, 306]
[306, 391]
[391, 82]
[82, 35]
[35, 902]
[902, 955]
[955, 13]
[955, 847]
[847, 835]
[83, 5698]
[698, 777]
[777, 896]
[896, 923]
[923, 940]
[940, 569]
[569, 53]
[53, 411]

Comment: @West1234 that's because I used `skip=1`. if you use it by default it gets that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my ugly-ish solution for this:

```
x = [38, 1200, 1200, 306, 306, 391, 391, 82, 82, 35, 35, 902, 902, 955, 955, 13, 955, 847, 847, 835, 83, 5698, 698, 777, 777, 896, 896, 923, 923, 940, 940, 569, 569, 53, 53, 411]

def weird_split(alist):
    sublist = []
    for i, n in enumerate(alist[:-1]):
        sublist.append(n)
        # make sure we only create a new list if the current one is not empty
        if len(sublist) > 1 and n != alist[i-1] and n != alist[i+1]:
            yield sublist
            sublist = []
    # always add the last element
    sublist.append(alist[-1])
    yield sublist

for sublist in weird_split(x):
    print sublist
```

And the output:

```
[38, 1200, 1200, 306, 306, 391, 391, 82, 82, 35, 35, 902, 902, 955, 955, 13]
[955, 847, 847, 835]
[83, 5698]
[698, 777, 777, 896, 896, 923, 923, 940, 940, 569, 569, 53, 53, 411]
```

Comment: Works for the new example as well

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you haven't defined behaviour for `[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]`, so this splits it into `[1, 0, 0, 1]`, `[0, 0]` and `[1]`.

Secondly, there are a lot of corner cases that need to be handled correctly, so it's longer than you might expect. This would also be shorted if it directly put things into lists, but generators are a good thing so I made sure not to do that.

Firstly, use the full iterator interface instead of the `yield` shortcut because it allows better sharing of state between the outer and inner iterables without making a new `subsection` generator each iteration. A nested `def` with `yield`s might be able to do this in less space, but in this case the wordiness is acceptable, I think.

So, set-up:

```
class repeating_sections:
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.iter = iter(iterable)

        try:
            self._cache = next(self.iter)
            self.finished = False
        except StopIteration:
            self.finished = True
```

We need to define the sub-iterator that yields until it finds a pair that doesn't match. Because the end would be removed from the iterator we need to `yield` it on the next call to `_subsection`, so store it in `_cache`.

```
    def _subsection(self):
        yield self._cache

        try:
            while True:
                item1 = next(self.iter)

                try:
                    item2 = next(self.iter)
                except StopIteration:
                    yield item1
                    raise

                if item1 == item2:
                    yield item1
                    yield item2

                else:
                    yield item1
                    self._cache = item2
                    return

        except StopIteration:
            self.finished = True
```

`__iter__` should return `self` for iterables:

```
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
```

`__next__` returns a subsection unless finished. Note that exhausting the section is important if behaiour is to be reliable.

```
    def __next__(self):
        if self.finished:
            raise StopIteration

        subsection = self._subsection()
        return subsection

        for item in subsection:
            pass
```

Some tests:

```
for item in repeating_sections(x):
    print(list(item))
#>>> [38, 1200, 1200, 306, 306, 391, 391, 82, 82, 35, 35, 902, 902, 955, 955, 13]
#>>> [955, 847, 847, 835, 835, 698, 698, 777, 777, 896, 896, 923, 923, 940, 940, 569, 569, 53, 53, 411]
#>>> [53, 1009, 1009, 1884]
#>>> [1009, 878]
#>>> [923, 886, 886, 511, 511, 942, 942, 1067, 1067, 1888, 1888, 243, 243, 1556]


for item in repeating_sections([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]):
    print(list(item))
#>>> [1, 0, 0, 1]
#>>> [0, 0]
#>>> [1]
```

Some timings to show this wasn't totally pointless:

```
SETUP="
x = [38, 1200, 1200, 306, 306, 391, 391, 82, 82, 35, 35, 902, 902, 955, 955, 13, 955, 847, 847, 835, 83, 5698, 698, 777, 777, 896, 896, 923, 923, 940, 940, 569, 569, 53, 53, 411]
x *= 5000

class repeating_sections:
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.iter = iter(iterable)

        try:
            self._cache = next(self.iter)
            self.finished = False
        except StopIteration:
            self.finished = True

    def _subsection(self):
        yield self._cache

        try:
            while True:
                item1 = next(self.iter)

                try:
                    item2 = next(self.iter)
                except StopIteration:
                    yield item1
                    raise

                if item1 == item2:
                    yield item1
                    yield item2

                else:
                    yield item1
                    self._cache = item2
                    return

        except StopIteration:
            self.finished = True

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.finished:
            raise StopIteration

        subsection = self._subsection()
        return subsection

        for item in subsection:
            pass


def weird_split(alist):
    sublist = []
    for i, n in enumerate(alist[:-1]):
        sublist.append(n)
        # make sure we only create a new list if the current one is not empty
        if len(sublist) > 1 and n != alist[i-1] and n != alist[i+1]:
            yield sublist
            sublist = []
    # always add the last element
    sublist.append(alist[-1])
    yield sublist
"

python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" "for section in repeating_sections(x):" "    for item in section: pass"
python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" "for section in weird_split(x):"        "    for item in section: pass"
```

Result:

```
10 loops, best of 3: 150 msec per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 207 msec per loop
```

Not a massive difference, but it's faster nonetheless.

Comment: If I understood correctly, `[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]` should split into `[1, 0, 0, 1]` and `[0, 0, 1]`

Comment: It hasn't been defined so I don't think you *can* say so. `[0, 0, 1]` isn't of the form `[a, (b, b)*, c]`.

Comment: I could be wrong, but it looks to me like the splitting should always happen *after* a number that isn't repeated.